# PHPMailer with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, phpmailer

I'm attempting to create a contact form for my site using PHPMailer and AngularJS with Gmail. I've followed the examples provided by PHPMailer themselves and a few online tutorials but I'm running into trouble. The page receives no error when it triggers the script but I never get the email from the form. Here is my code:

**AngularJS Markup:**

```
<div ng-controller="ContactCtrl" class="panel-body">
    <form ng-submit="submit(contactform)" name="contactform" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputName.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputName" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your Name" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputEmail.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputEmail" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputSubject.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputSubject" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject Message" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputMessage.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputMessage" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea ng-model="formData.inputMessage" class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..." required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="submitButtonDisabled">Send Message</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
    <p ng-class="result" style="padding: 15px; margin: 0;">{{ resultMessage }}</p>
</div>
```

**AngularJS Controller:**

```
angular.module('v2App')
  .controller('ContactCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = 'hidden'
    $scope.resultMessage;
    $scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
    $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
    $scope.submit = function(contactform) {
        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
        if (contactform.$valid) {
            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'contact-form.php',
                data    : $.param($scope.formData),  //param method from jQuery
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            }).success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result='bg-success';
                } else {
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result='bg-danger';
                }
            });
        } else {
            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
            $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed.';
            $scope.result='bg-danger';
        }
    }
});
```

**PHP.** The PHPMailer files are located within the phpmailer directory.

```
<?php
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['inputName']) && isset($_POST['inputEmail']) && isset($_POST['inputSubject']) && isset($_POST['inputMessage'])) {

    //check if any of the inputs are empty
    if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || empty($_POST['inputSubject']) || empty($_POST['inputMessage'])) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    //create an instance of PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From = $_POST['inputEmail'];
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['inputName'];
    $mail->AddAddress('my@emailaddress.com'); //recipient
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['inputSubject'];
    $mail->Body = "Name: " . $_POST['inputName'] . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputMessage']);

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');\
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "mygmailusername@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "passwordform";
    $mail->setFrom('mygmailusername@gmail.com', 'Contact Form');


    if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
        $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
    }

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thanks! We have received your message.');
    echo json_encode($data);

} else {

    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. I don't have any kind of logs I can refer to so I'm not sure what is causing this to fail. I've done all of the standard tests such as verifying the password etc. Two-step authentication is turned off for the account as it's a dummy account for sending out mail.

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any return from .php file??

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes Negative. The page just reloads.

Comment: add an alert("validate form"); after line "if (contactform.$valid) {" and check if its giving alert.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes It alerts.

Comment: Now can you print_r($_POST); in your .php file right after  "if (isset($_POST['inputName']) && isset($_POST['inputEmail']) && isset($_POST['inputSubject']) && isset($_POST['inputMessage'])) {" to check if all the values are posted properly?

Comment: Also add "$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;" right after "$mail->Password = "passwordform";" line. This will give you error details if theres any.

Comment: Just follow my last comment.

Comment: Yep sorry, had a typo in the code. Fixing that up. I'll get the actual error in just a moment here.

Comment: It would appear that it's working. Looks like the typo was the cause after all. Had a slash after the host name. Thanks!

Comment: `page reloads` ...  because you set `method` and `action` on form the form will submit by browser default process. See angular docs for forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error was caused by a typo in the host name part of the PHP file:

```
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');\
```

Should have been:

```
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
```